# android phonegap cordova webview events

Tags: java, android, cordova

In my code, I am properly using webview and handling onPageFinished and shouldOverrideUrlLoading events. Now I redefined it as DroidGap in order to handle its functions. I should then continue intercepting these events because if I override it, phonegap functions are not executed anymore (as I do on iOS)! how to embed it and handle described events? thank you

```
public class webPush extends Activity implements CordovaInterface{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to redefine it to DroidGap. You can use your own implementation using CordovaInterface and just copy the functions you need from DroidGap java class. That way you can edit existing code or add your own.

This is what the official PhoneGap documentation says:

> Modify your activity so that it implements the CordovaInterface. It is recommended that you implement the methods that are included. You may wish to copy the methods from /framework/src/org/apache/cordova/DroidGap.java, or you may wish to implement your own methods

[Embedding Cordova WebView on Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android)

Answer (score 0):

Embedding Webview we can do like this way basically

```
public class CordovaViewTestActivity extends Activity implements CordovaInterface {
    CordovaWebView cwv;
    /* Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        cwv = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialView);
        cwv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
```

If still you are getting the error ,kindly post your code along with logcat output,It will be easy to resolve the issue..

Comment: No problem on embedding cordovaWebView! I need to override its events and also keep calling default compiled ones! or modify pg classes.

Comment: @Jaume could you please add your codes..with respect to your desire solution..it will be good to understand

Comment: Hi, In CordovaWebview, WebviewClient is always null. I have posted the code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198029/get-cordova-webview-instance-and-loadurl-android (Edit 1). Please help me to resolve.