# Get Cordova webview instance and loadurl - Android

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

I need to load the external URL in CordovaWebview. I have the following code.

```
public class ActionBar extends CordovaActivity 
{   
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
     CordovaWebView webview = new CordovaWebView(this);
     Config.init(this);
     webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");       
}
}
```

The application crashes after some time.

**Log Details:**

```
08-08 12:42:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(32712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 12:42:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(32712): Process: com.example.actionbar, PID: 32712
08-08 12:42:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(32712): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-08 12:42:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.stopLoading(CordovaWebView.java:546)
08-08 12:42:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView$2.run(CordovaWebView.java:468)
08-08 12:42:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-08 12:42:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-08 12:42:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
08-08 12:42:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
08-08 12:42:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 12:42:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-08 12:42:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
08-08 12:42:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
08-08 12:42:44.490: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT 1**

```
public class GetCordovaWebview extends Activity implements CordovaInterface {

protected static Activity currentActivity;
private CordovaWebView cordova_webview;
private String TAG = "CORDOVA_ACTIVITY";
private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

// Android Activity Life-cycle events
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
    CordovaWebView webview = new CordovaWebView(this);
    Config.init(this);
    layout.addView(webview);
    setContentView(layout);
    webview.loadurl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (this.cordova_webview != null) {
        this.cordova_webview
                .loadUrl("javascript:try{cordova.require('cordova/channel').onDestroy.fire();}catch(e){console.log('exception firing destroy event from native');};");
        this.cordova_webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
        this.cordova_webview.removeAllViews();
        cordova_webview.handleDestroy();
    }
}

@Override
public Activity getActivity() {
    return this;
}

@Override
public ExecutorService getThreadPool() {
    return threadPool;
}

@Override
public Object onMessage(String message, Object obj) {
    Log.d(TAG, message);
    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
        super.finish();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setActivityResultCallback(CordovaPlugin cordovaPlugin) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setActivityResultCallback is unimplemented");
}

@Override
public void startActivityForResult(CordovaPlugin cordovaPlugin,
        Intent intent, int resultCode) {
    Log.d(TAG, "startActivityForResult is unimplemented");
}
```

}

Tried the above lines of code. But the application crashes. While debugging the Cordova 3.5 source, the **stopLoading() webview method called, the WebviewClient (viewClient.isCurrentlyLoading) variable (viewClient) is null**. Is there anything need to be changed for getting the CordovaWebview.

Comment: Is anyother way to get the CordovaWebview and load the URL dynamically?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // you need to call init() so the appView member gets initialized...
    super.init();
    appView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
}
```

Comment: How can I do this in iOS ?